# how can I use lodash filter in angular4

Tags: angular, lodash

I have an angularjs application where I subscribe to an event and get the file that is read in the below format. I get this in the form of a string.

00|name|34|name2|45|name3
00|lmn|55|lmn2|95|lmn3

Now I want to use Lodash libraries and find if any of the values between delimeter '|' is null and get those values which are null.
I have used lodash filter earlier, but didn't get an idea to which filter function should I use.

Also how I can include lodash.js into angular4 apps.

Comment: Try this `'00|name|34|name2|45|name3 00|lmn|55|lmn2|95|lmn3'.split('|').filter(val => val == 'null');`

Comment: its have nothing to do with angular.
you can use lodash in any js file and any js framework

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need lodash. Just split the string by the `|` character and filter accordingly: 
   `'string'.split('|').filter(item => item === 'null');`
2. If you still want to use lodash: 
   `import * as _ from 'lodash';`

Comment: thanks. I also want to know the index at which it is null